# How to split and take multiple strings from a url in c#?

Tags: c#, url, split

I have a string looking something like this:

```
/Gender=&Age=&Query=&Orgrimmar+l%C3%A4n=01&Stormwind+l%C3%A4n=07&Undercity+l%C3%A4n=09&Pag
```

I want a list of string with "Orgrimmar", "Stormwind" and "Undercity". How is this possible so that it splits AFTER Query and between & and + in order so that we avoid getting a string like this "Orgrimmar+l%C3%A4n=01&Stormwind".

Let us assume that we don't know the name of the strings.. :)

Updated, i still don't seem to get it to work. I have added a list of counties that i can use to validate this. However i still find it hard in this case. countyList is used to validate that the counties/cities in the url matches a pre-existing Collection.

```
        var countyQuery = Request.Url.Query;
        var counties = this._locationService.GetAllCounties();
        List<string> countyList = new List<string>();
        List<string> selectedCountiesList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var i in counties)
        {
            countyList.Add(i.Name);

        }

        Regex r = new Regex(@"&(.+?)\+");
        MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(countyQuery);

        foreach (Match curMatch in mc)
        {
            if (countyList.Contains(curMatch.Groups[1].Value))
            {
                selectedCountiesList.Add(curMatch.Groups[1].Value);
            }
        }



        return selectedCountiesList;
```

Changed url to be/?Gender=&Age=&Query=&county=13&county=08&county=01&Page=1
where 13, 08, 01 and so on is Id of the counties
The final solution was:
    var selectedCountyQuery = Request.QueryString
                       //CountySearch = "county"
[QueryStringParameters.CountySearch];
            List countyList = new List();

```
        List<string> selectedCounties = new List<string>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedCountyQuery))
        {
            var selectedCountiesArray = selectedCountyQuery.Split(new[]{ ',' });
            foreach (var selectedCounty in selectedCountiesArray)
            {
                selectedCounties.Add(selectedCounty);
            }
        }
        return selectedCounties;
```

Comment: What have u tried so far? What is the similarity of the strings??

Comment: I have tried defining a start and end index. The similarity is that they both starts with & and has a +.                                                                                                                           int startIndex = selectedCityQuery.IndexOf('&');
            int endIndex = selectedCityQuery.IndexOf('+');

Comment: Please show what you have tried and exactly what the issue is - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You can get all parameter and value with `Substring()` and `Split()` method.

Example :

```
var URL = "controller/method?var1=&var2=&var3=dsgdf";

var ParameterPart = URL.Split("?")[1];

var ParametersArray = ParameterPart.Split("&");
//output : ["var1=","var2=","var3=dsgdf"];

foreach(var Parameter in ParametersArray)
{
   var ParameterName= Parameter.Split("=")[0];
   var ParameterValue= Parameter.Split("=")[1];
}
```

Comment: Thank u! I will try this! :)

Comment: Yes it worked. I took Another aproach and it worked. Thank for the tip tho it was great :) <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex and extract the matches:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"&(.+?)\+");
MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(s);
```

Then you can itterate your desired strings (in this case wow cities) like:

```
    foreach(Match curMatch in mc) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(curMatch.Groups[1].Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] numbers ={ "/Gender=&Age=&Query=&Orgrimmar+l%C3%A4n=01&Stormwind+l%C3%A4n=07&Undercity+l%C3%A4n=09&Pag"};
string sPattern = @"(?<=&Orgrimmar)+";
    foreach (string s in numbers){
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, sPattern)){
System.Console.WriteLine(" - valid");}
else{System.Console.WriteLine(" - invalid");}
```

Output: valid

```
string[] numbers ={ "/Gender=&Age=&Query=Orgrimmar+l%C3%A4n=01&Stormwind+l%C3%A4n=07&Undercity+l%C3%A4n=09&Pag"};
```

Output: invalid

Further to check two parameters:

```
    string[] numbers ={ "/Gender=&Age=&Query=&Orgrimmar+l%C3%A4n=01&Stormwind+l%C3%A4n=07&Undercity+l%C3%A4n=09&Pag"};

string sPattern = @"(?<=&Orgrimmar)+";
string sPattern2 = @"(?<=&Stormwind)+";
foreach (string s in numbers){
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, sPattern) && System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, sPattern2))
```

...